# How to calculate Duration at a specific range T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The following query will build a tempoary table with Item 1, 2, and 3. The idea of this is to generate a simple dataset of an issue I am facing.

Running it will produce the following result:

```
Target  PollTime    PrevPollTime    Duration
-------------------------------------------------------------
Item1   2014-11-18 00:12:14.000 2014-11-18 00:05:14.000 7
Item3   2014-11-18 00:08:14.000 2014-11-18 00:02:14.000 6
Item3   2014-11-18 00:14:14.000 2014-11-18 00:08:14.000 6
```

However if you change the @EndDate parameter to **'2014-11-18 00:11:14'** the result is:

```
Item3   2014-11-18 00:08:14.000 2014-11-18 00:02:14.000 6
```

My issue is that I would like to add the functionality that the result would be:

```
Item1   2014-11-18 00:11:14.000 2014-11-18 00:05:14.000 6
Item3   2014-11-18 00:08:14.000 2014-11-18 00:02:14.000 6
```

And if the @EndDate parameter was changed to **'2014-11-18 00:25:14'**:

```
Item1   2014-11-18 00:12:14.000 2014-11-18 00:05:14.000 7
Item1   2014-11-18 00:25:14.000 2014-11-18 00:14:14.000 11
Item2   2014-11-18 00:25:14.000 2014-11-18 00:14:14.000 11
Item3   2014-11-18 00:08:14.000 2014-11-18 00:02:14.000 6
Item3   2014-11-18 00:14:14.000 2014-11-18 00:08:14.000 6
Item3   2014-11-18 00:25:14.000 2014-11-18 00:14:14.000 11
```

The @EndDate Parameter would have to be include somehow.

```
DROP TABLE #TempTable
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
Target VARCHAR(255),
PollTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item1', CAST('2014-11-18 00:00:14.000' AS    DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item1', CAST('2014-11-18 00:01:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item1', CAST('2014-11-18 00:02:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item1', CAST('2014-11-18 00:03:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item1', CAST('2014-11-18 00:04:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item1', CAST('2014-11-18 00:05:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item1', CAST('2014-11-18 00:12:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item1', CAST('2014-11-18 00:13:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item1', CAST('2014-11-18 00:14:14.000' AS DATETIME))

INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:00:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:01:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:02:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:03:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:04:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:05:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:06:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:07:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:08:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:09:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:10:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:11:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:12:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:13:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item2', CAST('2014-11-18 00:14:14.000' AS DATETIME))

INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item3', CAST('2014-11-18 00:01:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item3', CAST('2014-11-18 00:02:14.000' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item3', CAST('2014-11-18 00:08:14.000' AS    DATETIME))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Target, PollTime) VALUES('Item3', CAST('2014-11-18 00:14:14.000' AS DATETIME))

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = CAST('2014-11-18 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = CAST('2014-11-18 00:15:00' AS DATETIME);

WITH Data AS (
SELECT *
FROM #TempTable 
WHERE PollTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
), 
RankData AS 
(
SELECT * FROM Data A
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 
            PrevPollTime = PollTime
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT *, 
                Rn = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY PollTime DESC)
            FROM #TempTable B
            WHERE B.Target = A.Target AND B.PollTime < A.PollTime 
        ) T WHERE Rn = 1 
    ) AS C          
WHERE (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, C.PrevPollTime, A.PollTime) > 5)
)
SELECT *, 
Duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PrevPollTime, PollTime) 
FROM RankData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your CTE with two CASE clausules. Here is modified code:
(modified version, try it :) , now it working :-))

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = CAST('2014-11-18 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = CAST('2014-11-18 00:25:14' AS DATETIME);


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempTable2
SELECT Target,PollTime 
INTO #TempTable2
FROM #TempTable
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT Target,@EndDate AS PollTime
FROM #TempTable
WHERE @EndDate > PollTime;



WITH Data AS (
SELECT DISTINCT Target,CASE WHEN PollTime > @EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE PollTime END AS PollTime
FROM #TempTable2
WHERE PollTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND (CASE WHEN PollTime > @EndDate THEN PollTime ELSE @EndDate END)
), 
RankData AS 
(
SELECT * FROM Data A
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 
            PrevPollTime = PollTime
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT *, 
                Rn = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY PollTime DESC)
            FROM #TempTable2 B
            WHERE B.Target = A.Target AND B.PollTime < A.PollTime 
        ) T WHERE Rn = 1 
    ) AS C          
WHERE (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, C.PrevPollTime, A.PollTime) > 5)
)
SELECT *, 
Duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PrevPollTime, PollTime) 
FROM RankData
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it works for my first case when you set '2014-11-18 00:11:14' however it does not work when the @EndDate exceeds for example in my second case '2014-11-18 00:25:14'.

Comment: Do you think what I want to do is possible with one query. I would it be better to check for missing data at the end separately?

Comment: yea, today i find solution :)

Comment: Code is modified , try it :)

Answer (score 0):

I added a UNION where I get the Max date and make my compairson, rewriting my query a little.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = CAST('2014-11-18 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = CAST('2014-11-18 00:20:14' AS DATETIME);

WITH Data AS (
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Target, 
    PollTime = CASE WHEN PollTime > @EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE PollTime END
FROM #TempTable 
WHERE PollTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND (CASE WHEN PollTime > @EndDate THEN PollTime ELSE @EndDate END)
), 
RankData AS 
(
SELECT * FROM Data A
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 
            PrevPollTime = PollTime
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT *, 
                Rn = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY PollTime DESC)
            FROM #TempTable B
            WHERE B.Target = A.Target AND B.PollTime < A.PollTime 
        ) T WHERE Rn = 1 
    ) AS C          
UNION 
SELECT 
    Target,
    PollTime = @EndDate,
    PrevPollTime = MAX(PollTime)
FROM Data A
WHERE PollTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate      
GROUP BY Target             
)
SELECT *, 
Duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PrevPollTime, PollTime) 
FROM RankData WHERE (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PrevPollTime, PollTime) > 5)
```